# How to group similar items in a list using Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Given a list of tuples like this:

```
dic = [(1,"aa"),(1,"cc"),(2,"aa"),(3,"ff"),(3,"gg"),(1,"bb")]
```

How to group items of *dic* resulting in a list *grp* where,

```
grp  = [(1,["aa","bb","cc"]), (2, ["aa"]), (3, ["ff","gg"])]
```

I'm actually a newcomer to Haskell...and seems to be falling in love with it..
Using *group* or *groupBy* in *Data.List* will only group similar adjacent items in a list.
I wrote an inefficient function for this, but it results in memory failures as  I need to process a very large coded string list. Hope you would help me find a more efficient way.

Comment: Looks like a homework or something. Better to add your approach and ask the community for ways to improve it instead of just asking the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newcomer to stackoverflow..apologies for not being aware of community rules.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy, groupBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

myGroup :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, [b])]
myGroup = map (\l -> (fst . head $ l, map snd l)) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
          . sortBy (comparing fst)
```

This works by first sorting the list with `sortBy`:

```
[(1,"aa"),(1,"cc"),(2,"aa"),(3,"ff"),(3,"gg"),(1,"bb")]     
=> [(1,"aa"),(1,"bb"),(1,"cc"),(2,"aa"),(3,"ff"),(3,"gg")]
```

then grouping the list elements by the associated key with `groupBy`:

```
[(1,"aa"),(1,"bb"),(1,"cc"),(2,"aa"),(3,"ff"),(3,"gg")] 
=> [[(1,"aa"),(1,"bb"),(1,"cc")],[(2,"aa")],[(3,"ff"),(3,"gg")]]
```

and then transforming the grouped items to tuples with `map`:

```
[[(1,"aa"),(1,"bb"),(1,"cc")],[(2,"aa")],[(3,"ff"),(3,"gg")]] 
=> [(1,["aa","bb","cc"]), (2, ["aa"]), (3, ["ff","gg"])]`)
```

Testing:

```
> myGroup dic
[(1,["aa","bb","cc"]),(2,["aa"]),(3,["ff","gg"])]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This really works. I'm actually a newcomer to Haskell and I wasn't aware much about libraries. Thanks again for the clever answer!.

Comment: @ Mikhail : Hey, are you sure this works even if similar keyed values are not adjacent? for an example if dic = [(1,"aa"),(2,"bb"),(1,"cc")]? result should be [(1, ["aa","cc"]), (2, "bb")].

Comment: ^@td123 In this case, you should sort the list beforehand.

Answer (score 66):

Whenever possible, reuse library code.

```
import Data.Map
sortAndGroup assocs = fromListWith (++) [(k, [v]) | (k, v) <- assocs]
```

Try it out in ghci:

```
*Main> sortAndGroup [(1,"aa"),(1,"cc"),(2,"aa"),(3,"ff"),(3,"gg"),(1,"bb")]
fromList [(1,["bb","cc","aa"]),(2,["aa"]),(3,["gg","ff"])]
```

**EDIT** In the comments, some folks are worried about whether `(++)` or `flip (++)` is the right choice. The documentation doesn't say which way things get associated; you can find out by experimenting, or you can sidestep the whole issue using [difference lists](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list):

```
sortAndGroup assocs = ($[]) <$> fromListWith (.) [(k, (v:)) | (k, v) <- assocs]
-- OR
sortAndGroup = fmap ($[]) . M.fromListWith (.) . map (fmap (:))
```

These alternatives are about the same length as the original, but they're a bit less readable to me.

Comment: Really cool solution. Never would've thought of it, but it makes a lot of sense, considering the nature of Data.Map.

Comment: This was going to be my answer. I briefly gave pause to think about efficiency though - I use the `toList . fromListWith op` pattern a lot, but I wonder how expensive the conversions to and from `Map` are compared to walking over the list and grouping manually.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor This solution is O(n log n), which is the best you can hope for given the constraints.

Comment: @DanielWagner Isn't converting every element to a list and then concatenating lists kinda expensive?

Comment: @akshay2000 It shouldn't be, no; converting to a list is very cheap, and prepending singleton lists is cheap. If it turns out that this is appending singleton lists instead, it's easy to fix: just use `fromListWith (flip (++))` instead of `fromListWith (++)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Follow up: How do we know if it is prepending or appending? There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of knowing that.

Comment: @akshay Compare the performance of `fromListWith (++) [((), [()]) | x <- [1..10000]]` with the performance of `fromListWith (flip (++)) [((), [()]) | x <- [1..10000]]`. ;-) (Spoilers: `(++)` is the right one, not `flip (++)`.)

Comment: @DanielWagner While this works, this feels a bit like a hack to me. Isn't there a 'correct by design' approach what is applicable on a wider scale?

Comment: @akshay2000 Sorry, I can't be held accountable for your feelings. If you have an objective reason to dislike this solution, I'd be happy to discuss it, potential mitigations, and their tradeoffs.

Comment: @DanielWagner Fair enough. I just wanted to know if there was a way to know this information without experimentation. As in conceptually.

Comment: @akshay2000 [Read the source, of course.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/src/Data-Map-Internal.html#fromListWith)

Comment: @akshay2000 it's a docs deficiency. it should've mentioned the order, as it already does for [`insertWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:insertWith) / `insertWithKey`, which the `fromListWith` function uses anyhow, judging from [its source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/src/Data.Map.Strict.Internal.html#line-1529).

Answer (score 8):

Also you can use [TransformListComp](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#generalised-list-comprehensions) extension, for example:

```
Prelude> :set -XTransformListComp 
Prelude> import GHC.Exts (groupWith, the)
Prelude GHC.Exts> let dic = [ (1, "aa"), (1, "bb"), (1, "cc") , (2, "aa"), (3, "ff"), (3, "gg")]
Prelude GHC.Exts> [(the key, value) | (key, value) <- dic, then group by key using groupWith]
[(1,["aa","bb","cc"]),(2,["aa"]),(3,["ff","gg"])]
```

Answer (score 4):

1. If the list is not sorted on the first element, I don't think you can do better than O(nlog(n)).

   - One simple way would be to just `sort` and then use anything from the answer of second part.
   - You can use from `Data.Map` a map like `Map k [a]` to use first element of tuple as key and keep on adding to the values.
   - You can write your own complex function, which even after you all the attempts will still take O(nlog(n)).
2. If list is sorted on the first element as is the case in your example, then the task is trivial for something like groupBy as given in the answer by @Mikhail or use foldr and there are numerous other ways.

An example of using foldr is here:

```
  grp :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [(a,[b])]
  grp = foldr f []
     where 
       f (z,s) [] = [(z,[s])] 
       f (z,s) a@((x,y):xs)  | x == z = (x,s:y):xs 
                             | otherwise = (z,[s]):a
```

Comment: Thank you for the info...I'm going to use Data.Map.

Answer (score 0):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TransformListComp #-}

import GHC.Exts
import Data.List
import Data.Function (on)

process :: [(Integer, String)] -> [(Integer, [String])]
process list = [(the a, b) |  let info = [ (x, y) | (x, y) <- list, then    sortWith by y ], (a, b) <- info, then group by a using groupWith]
```