# Haskell: Combine integers in a list of tuples

Tags: list, function, haskell, tuples

I need to get from here:

```
[(2,"a"), (1,"a"), (1,"b"), (1,"c"), (2,"dd")]
```

to here:

```
[([1, 2], "a"), ([1], "b"), ([1], "c"), ([2], "dd")]
```

So far I have

```
combineInts listTuple = someFunc (map (\(num, str) -> ([num], str)) listTuple)
```

where "someFunc" is the bit I still need to figure out and implement. I believe it should utilize foldr, map, and/or intercalate to accomplish my goal. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like you want to do some kind of grouping with a capital-M `Map`.

Comment: no, it's a data structure from Data.Map.

Comment: I think a better duplicate would be [How to group similar items in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12398458/791604); the current duplicate's answer appears to be primarily about formatting, whereas this question is primarily about the grouping part.

Comment: @DanielWagner That would be a better question to link back to, I mostly closed it as a duplicate because OP asked what is essentially the same question twice.  I'll see if I can reopen and then mark it as a duplicate of the question you linked. EDIT: I can't vote to close it again for a while, feel free to throw your vote in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (groupBy, sort, sortBy)

out = map f . groupBy ((==) `on` snd) . sortBy (compare `on` snd) $ input
  where input = [(2,"a"),(1,"a"),(1,"b"),(1,"c"),(2,"dd")]
        f xs@(x:_) = (sort $ map fst xs, snd x)

main = print out
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `groupBy` if you order the list first:

```
import Data.List (groupBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.Function (on)

map (\l@((_,c):_) -> (map fst l, c))  $ groupBy (on (==) snd) $ sortBy (comparing snd) inputList
```

Comment: This assumes all elements with the same `snd` already occur together in the input. If you sort first, you make sure that's not a problem.