# Combine tuples based on first element (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

In Haskell, I have a list of tuples in which each tuple in the list consists of a string and a number.  I was able to sort the list in ASCII order by the strings:

```
[("apple",1), ("apple",2), ("cat",1), ("cat",2), ("dog",3)]
```

Now I need to combine all tuples that consist of the same string (taking case into consideration). So, the desired output would be:

```
[("apple",[1,2]), ("cat",[1,2]), ("dog",[3])]
```

The new output list would consist of tuples, in which each tuple consists of a string and a list of ints.

I'm new to Haskell so I'm still trying to get used to the Haskell way of thinking. I'm considering using takeWhile, but I'm not completely sure...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use `groupBy` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398458/how-to-group-similar-items-in-a-list-using-haskell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769930/haskell-combine-integers-in-a-list-of-tuples

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the duplicate; I was trying to search for a similar question but wasn't sure how to phrase it exactly.