# string to list of lists of rhyming words

Tags: list, haskell

My goal is a function which takes a sentence and returns a list of lists with the words rhyming (rhyming = last 3 chars are equal).

Example: `"Six sick hicks nick six slick bricks with picks and sticks."` ->

```
[[Six,six],[sick,nick,slick],[hicks,bricks,picks,sticks],[with]]
```

This is my code so far (bsort is bubblesort):

```
rhymeWords:: String -> [[String]]
rhymeWords "" = []
rhymeWords xs = bsort (words (reverse xs))
```

I do not know how to translate it into code but I would like to take the first three chars of the first string and put them into a list. Then take the next String and test if it is equal to the first. If true put the second string into the first list otherwise create a second list. Then move on to the third string, each time testing with previous lists.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: A minor variant of [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12398993/791604): `\s -> elems . fromListWith (++) $ [(take 3 (reverse w), [w]) | w <- words s]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code groups rhymes as requested, although it converts all characters to lower case.

```
import Data.List (sort)
import Data.Char (toLower)

rhymeWords:: String -> [[String]]
rhymeWords "" = []
rhymeWords xs = [map reverse g | g <- groupRhymes (sortRhymes xs) []]
    where sortRhymes xs = sort $ map reverse (words [toLower x | x <- xs])

groupRhymes :: [String] -> [[String]] -> [[String]]
groupRhymes [] acc     = acc
groupRhymes (x:xs) acc = case acc of
                            [] -> groupRhymes xs [[x]]
                            _  -> if take 3 x == take 3 (head (last acc)) 
                                    then groupRhymes xs ((init acc) ++ [(last acc) ++ [x]])
                                    else groupRhymes xs (acc ++ [[x]])
```

Example result:

```
hymeWords "Six sick hicks nick six slick bricks with picks and sticks"
[["and"],["with"],["slick","nick","sick"],["hicks","picks","bricks","sticks"],["six","six"]]
```

Note that the example input doesn't have a period at the end of the sentence, because the last word would include it and break the sorting. You'll need to fiddle a bit with presented code if you need to pass sentences with a period.

Comment: Thank you! Fiddling now! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you have to group items together, you can use [`Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html)'s grouping higher order functions. With [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) you can easily solve your problem just by writing your grouping function. In your case, you want to group words that rhyme together. You just have to write the function `rhyming`:

```
rhyming :: String -> String -> Bool
rhyming word1 word2 = last3 (lower word1) == last3 (lower word2)
    where
        last3 = take 3 . reverse  -- if you wanted `last3` to return the last three characters in order, you'd just have to apply `reverse` to the result, but that's unnecessary here
        lower = map toLower
```

So your `rhymeWords` function can be written like so:

```
import Data.List (groupBy, sort)
import Data.Char (toLower)

rhyming :: String -> String -> Bool
rhyming word1 word2 = last3 (lowercase word1) == last3 (lowercase word2)
    where
        last3 = take 3 . reverse
        lowercase = map toLower

rhymeWords :: String -> [[String]]
rhymeWords = groupBy rhyming . map reverse . sort . map reverse . words
```

The `map reverse . sort . map reverse` thing is needed since `groupBy` groups elements that are next to another. It groups words that are likely to rhyme together.

Comment: You can remove the `reverse` part from your `rhyming` function and the first `map reverse` from `rhymeWords`. They are sort of "cancelling each other out". Other than that, nice answer (a lot more readable that the one I came up with). I was trying to use `groupBy` at the beginning, but failed...

Comment: [Kapol](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3053082/kapol): Since `rhyming` and `rhymeWords` are two separate functions, they need to be "standalone". What I mean is that they should work in any condition. However if I put the `rhyming` function in a `where clause`, it would make more sense because it would exist only in `rhymeWords`'s context. Nice answer too :)

Comment: @baxbaxwalanuksiwe Thanks for the clarification.