# Group by first element of a list of tuple and apply function to all grouped second elements

Tags: list, haskell, group-by, tuples

I have a list

`[(8,2),(3,2),(3,1),(10,2),(10,6)] :: [(Int,Int)]`

and I want to get a list of tuples which is grouped by the first element of the tuple list. Also I would like to have a function applied for all grouped tuples, e.g. the sum.

After applying the group by and the function `(+)` I expect the result:

`[(8,2),(3,3),(10,8)] :: [(Int,Int)]`

How can I do this with Haskell?

---

EDIT

This is not an exact duplicate to 
[How to group similar items in a list using Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398458/how-to-group-similar-items-in-a-list-using-haskell) because I also want to know how to apply a function to every second element in a grouped tuple list.

---

I tried the following and I think it works now.

```
test :: Eq a => Tree a -> [(a,Int)]
test t = map (foldl1 sumZahlwerte) grouped
  where grouped = groupBy (\c d -> fst c == fst d) (getTuple t)

sumZahlwerte :: Eq a => (a,Int) -> (a,Int) ->  (a,Int)
sumZahlwerte (b,c) (_,e) = (b,c+e)
```

where `getTuple t` returns a `[(a,Int)]` list.

Feedback is appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I think that I could use the [groupBy function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy). But I don't know how.

Comment: Exactly. Now you just need a function that takes two tuples and returns True if their first elements are equal. Note through that `group` only groups consecutive elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a homework/study assignment so I will only give a few hints:

- you already named the most important function you need `groupBy` (from `Data.List`)
- moreover you need something to group with - you can either use a lambda expression, or the little function `on` provided by the `Data.Function` module - `` (==) `on` fst `` would be an idiomatic way to write this in haskell, but for the exercise write up a lambda function - that does the "comparison"
- after the grouping you have something of type `[[(Int,Int)]]` and with the handy functions `map` and `foldr1` you can then add those pairs - provided you have a function `add2 :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int)` that adds the 2nd components

Comment: Note, that normally you would want to use `foldr` instead of `foldr1`, because `foldr1` fails for `[]`. However, since `group` never creates empty group-lists (by which I mean something like `[[]]`, `[]`), here `foldr1` is fine.