# Creating a function for checking anagrams in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, recursion, tail-recursion, anagram

So I'm trying to create a function that takes a list of words and returns the anagrams in a new list. This is what I have so far:

```
quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort []     = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
    where
        lesser  = filter (< p) xs
        greater = filter (>= p) xs

sub(a,[]) = []
sub(a,b:c) = if a == b then c else b:(sub(a,c))

sublist([],a) = a
sublist(a:b,c) = sublist(b,sub(a,c))

anagram a b = quicksort (a) == quicksort (b)

find a,[] = nil
find (a, b:c) = if anagram a b then b:(find(a,c)) else find(a,c)

listana [] = nil
listana (a:c) = list:(listana(sublist(list,a:c)))
              where list = a:(find(a,c))
```

I'm pretty sure there is a problem with my find function.
Oh and I'm new to Haskell so please go easy on me.

Comment: Try adding explicit type signatures to your functions. GHC's error messages should (hopefully) help you find the problem with your code. Also, in Haskell you can write a function with 2 arguments (`f :: (a, b) -> c`) as a curried function (`f :: a -> b -> c`)

Answer (score 1):

Nice start!

The minimal change needed to make this compile is to replace `nil` with `[]` everywhere, and to wrap parentheses around the argument to `find`. So:

```
-- change one
find (a,[]) = []

-- change two
listana [] = []
```

There are many improvements available from there. I encourage you to poke through the `Data.List` module and see if any of the functions implemented there look useful. There is also a standard trick that uses `Data.Map` to group together items that makes this a one-liner; see [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12398993/791604) for a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Given a word and a list of potential anagrams, you will be returned all the true anagrams in that list.

```
type ListOfPossibleAnagrams = [String]
type Anagrams = [String]

anagramFinder :: String -> ListOfPossibleAnagrams -> Anagrams
anagramFinder [] _ = []
anagramFinder word [] = []
anagramFinder word [x] = if isAnagram word x then [x] else []
anagramFinder word (x:xs) = if isAnagram word x then x : anagramFinder word xs else [] : anagramFinder word xs
    where len1= length word
          len2 = length x


isAnagram:: String -> String -> Bool
isAnagram [] word2 = True
isAnagram (x:xs) word2
    | x `elem` word2 = isAnagram xs word2
    |otherwise = False
```