# Haskell: How do I write a function to combine my list of lists of tuples into a list of tuples?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I am learning Haskell and I am unsure how to write a function to access my list.

The data I am trying to modify is:

```
[[("String",1, "String", "ABC", 2.0)],[("String",1, "String", "DEF", 2.0),("String",4, "String", "DEF", 2.0)]]
```

Currently, the data is grouped together based on the last string ("ABC" or "DEF"). I want to combine the information to get an output of:

```
[("String",1, "String", "ABC", 2.0),("String",5, "String", "DEF", 4.0)]
```

where the strings don't change but the int/floats get added together.

The code I currently have is:

```
combine :: [(a)] -> (a)
combine [(a)] = (a)
```

I am just testing out to see if I can access the lists of different sizes but it doesn't work. It gives me an error when I try to access the other set of list.

```
[("CS",273,"A",1,"Lewis, Buck",1.66),*** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function combineInfo
```

Comment: The technique I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12398993/791604) can be pretty trivially adapted to this variation.

Answer (score 3):

Your function `combine` is defined to take a list of a single element and return that element; given a list of zero or more than one item, it’ll raise a runtime error as you observed. The compiler will warn about “non-exhaustive patterns” like this with warnings enabled, e.g., `-Wall`.

If you have a container of values and you want to combine them all in some way, that’s a good indication that you can use a fold. Looking at just this sublist:

```
sublist = [("String",1, "String", "DEF", 2.0),("String",4, "String", "DEF", 2.0)]
```

You can combine these values with `foldr1` (or `foldl1`):

```
foldr1 :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
```

Which is `(a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a` when `t` = `[]`.

```
combineGroup xs = foldr1 combine xs
  where
    combine
      (_, x, _, _, y)                 -- Current item in list
      (s1, totalX, s2, name, totalY)  -- Accumulator for results
      = (s1, totalX + x, s2, name, totalY + y)
```

This assumes the group is never empty; if it can be empty, use `foldr` (or `foldl'`) to supply an initial “default” value for the accumulator:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

Then, to apply this function to every group in the outer list, simply use `map`:

```
map combineGroup groups
```

If you want to do this with direct recursion as a learning exercise, look at the definitions of `map` and `foldr` in the standard library and try to manually inline them into a single function.

Another good way to improve your code would be to replace these tuples with a data type, e.g.:

```
data Info = Info
  { infoString1, infoString2 :: String
  , infoX :: Int
  , infoName :: String
  , infoY :: Double
  } deriving (Show)  -- Add other classes like Eq, Ord, &c. as needed.
```

Then the fold can be written more clearly using a *record update* to update only the fields you care about, without having to manually plumb around the irrelevant fields:

```
combineGroup xs = foldr1 combine xs
  where
    combine current acc = acc
      { x = infoX acc + infoX current
      , y = infoY acc + infoY current
      }

-- OR

{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
combineGroup xs = foldr1 combine xs
  where
    combine Info{ x, y } acc@Info{ x = totalX, y = totalY }
      = acc { x = totalX + x, y = totalY + y }
```