# Haskell: How do I combine a list of list of tuples using foldr?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, fold

I want to combine my list but I need to pass in a dummy initial value which is why I want to use 'foldr'.

My current list is:

```
[[(1, "Bob J", 4.0)],[(1, "Bill J", 2.5),(2,"Bill J", 2.7)]]
```

I want to combine the list based on their names but I also need to do arithmetic when I am combining the number.

My current code is:

```
grp xs = foldr combine xs
  where
    combine
    (x,_,y)
    (totalX,_,totalY)
    = (totalX+x,_,totalY+fromIntegral x *y)
```

This returns an error. I want totalX and totalY to initially be zero so it doesn't mess with the calculations. How do I do this?

Edit: I want my output to be in the same format so I want:

[(1,"Bob J", 4.0],(3,"Bill J", 2.6)]

Comment: What is the error that you see?

Comment: Looks like yet another variant of [group similar items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12398458/791604)... but I'm not certain enough to close as a dupe, because the grouping step appears to already be done, and only the combination step remains. Even so I'd still probably end up using the code I suggested at the linked question unless the grouping that precedes this question had somehow been done in better than O(n log n) time.

Comment: all you need is `map`, and `map f = foldr ((:) . f) []`.

Comment: @WillNess this doesn't detail how to combine the elements.

Comment: @TheInternet *small* steps... either the OP would get to the solution from that little hint, or they can always ask for clarifications. :)

Answer (score 1):

First I would flatten your list (use `concat`), then accumulate the values into a `Map` recursively. While accumulating, I would ensure that you upsert existing values with addition (this is what the `add` function does).

```
module Main where                                                                                                                                             

import           Data.List                                                                                                                                    
import qualified Data.Map  as M                                                                                                                               

main = print $ makeMap vals                                                                                                                                   

makeMap :: (Ord k, Num a, Num b) => [(a, k, b)] -> M.Map k (a, b)                                                                                             
makeMap = foldl' go mempty                                                                                                                                    
  where                                                                                                                                                       
    go m (x,name,y) = M.insertWith add name (x,y) m                                                                                                           
    add (a,b) (c,d) = (a+c,b+d)                                                                                                                               

vals = concat [[(1, "Bob J", 4.0)],[(1, "Bill J", 2.5),(2,"Bill J", 2.7)]]
```

Result is

```
λ> main                                                                                                                                                       
fromList [("Bill J",(3,5.2)),("Bob J",(1,4.0))]
```

Comment: doing O(n log n) when O(n) is possible, is not generally a recommended thing. the groups are already there, and you propose to destroy them and then go to work to recreate them.

Comment: We could use a mutable hash table to get O(n), but yes `Map` insertion is logarithmic.

Comment: Also, to be clear, the values themselves aren't actually destroyed, GHC will share them. @WillNess

Comment: `concat` 'destroys' the *groups*, as in, forgets the *grouping*.

Comment: @WillNess the grouping isn't necessary to solve the problem. Plus, the OP made it clear he wanted to combine the lists based on name irrespective of grouping.

Comment: they did, but it looks like it was an error on their part. the grouping of course is essential, either explicit in the list (as shown in the question) or implicit in the Map (as in your answer).