# haskell how to check two lists of tuples are equal and take union

Tags: list, tuples

I am a new self-leaner in Haskell. firstly, I want to write a function to check if two lists of tuples are equal. Each tuple has a key and value

secondly, I want a function to union two lists of tuples

I tried several ways and tried many times but seems couldn't meet my requirements. could anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: [How to group similar items in a list using Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12398458/791604)

Comment: To expand on Wilem's question:  perhaps it's easier to give us an example that does not show the behaviour you want - in this case two lists of pairs for which your current solution returns true when it should say false (or vice versa). From there we could work towards fixing your code.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x as for testing the equality, [('a',2),('b',1)] and [('b',1),('a',2)] it says False but it should be true

Comment: I am just trying to load the code you posted on my machine. It has multiple error messages - the first is that `lisLength` is undefined. Does loading what you posted into a fresh instance of ghci work for you? (The first step is to get your code to compile, then we can look at the behaviour)

Comment: @lambda.xy.x I have added the code for remaining functions. thanks!

Comment: Ah much less error messages now :-) I have one left, that's probably coming from `|itemInlis n lis1==False = (n,t2):`  -- I assume you would like to append some remaining list here?

Comment: As far as I see, `lisSum` is not (even indirectly) called by `lisEqual`, so we can disregard it for the moment. But then even `lisEqual [] [] == False` so there must be some trouble in the base case. ( `lisEqual  [('b',1)] [('b',1)] == False` as well )

Comment: @lambda.xy.x I have appended it now. thanks!

Comment: Question for later: what should be the result of `lisSum [('a',1), ('a',2)] [('a',3)]`?

Comment: @lambda.xy.x should be [('a',6)]

Comment: Just to be sure, does that also mean `lisEqual [('a',1), ('a',2)] [('a',3)] == True`?

Comment: That simplifies matters :-) It could be helpful to write a function that checks that all the first elements of a list of tuples are different. If this property holds, you could go through the first list and find the correspondent of each element in the second list and check for equality. Together with the length property that should ensure that the lists contain the same elements. (The solutions using sorting have better computational complexity, but then if we only have `Eq a`, not `Ord a` this becomes a bit tricky)

Comment: Btw I just realized, you might just want to modify `itemInLis` to `itemCount :: Eq a => a -> Lis a -> Times` that returns the second argument of the tuple instead of just true/false. If you are processing the tuple `(x,n)` you only need to check if `n == itemCount x lis2` (and error conditions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion: Start with a function that extracts the combined keys from two lists:

```
allKeys :: Eq a => Lis a -> Lis a -> [a]
```

So `allKeys [('a',2),('b',2),('c',3)] [('b',2),('a',1),('d',3)]` is `['a','b','c','d']`.
Hint: Extract all keys from both lists, merge them to one list, then remove duplicates from that list (there are standard functions for all these tasks).

The function is useful both for checking equality and computing the sums:

- To check equality, just check that looking up each key in the first list gives the same result as looking it up in the second list.
- To compute the sums, just pair every key up with the sum of lookups in both original lists.

One thing to consider: is the list `[('a',0)]` is ment to be identical to `[]`? Otherwise you should use a lookup function that returns `Maybe Int` and gives `Just 0` for key 'a' in the first case and `Nothing` in the second case.

Let me know if this is not homework and I can give you code.

Edit: Code! :)

The code below is slightly simplified compared to how I would normally write it, but not by much. There are probably several library functions you are not familiar with, including nub (for removing duplicates) which is imported from Data.List.

```
import Data.List(nub)

type Times = Int
type Lis a = [(a,Times)] 

count :: Eq a => Lis a -> a -> Times
count xs x = case lookup x xs of
  Nothing -> 0 -- x is not in the list
  Just n  -> n -- x is in the list associated with n

-- Extract all keys by taking the first value in each pair
keys :: Lis a -> [a]
keys xs = map fst xs 

-- Extract the union of all keys of two lists
allKeys :: Eq a => Lis a -> Lis a -> [a]
allKeys xs ys = nub (keys xs ++ keys ys)

lisEquals :: Eq a=> Lis a -> Lis a -> Bool
lisEquals xs ys = all test (allKeys xs ys) 
  where
    -- Check that a key maps to the same value in both lists
    test k = count xs k == count ys k

lisSum :: Eq a => Lis a -> Lis a -> Lis a
lisSum xs ys = map countBoth (allKeys xs ys)
  where
    -- Build a new list element from a key
    countBoth k = (k,count xs k + count ys k)
```

Comment: this is not a homework. I am a self-learner and just tried to write some functions. could you give me code so that I can compare with mine, thanks a lot

Comment: @cynn Code added. A beginner writing this code would use a lot more pattern matching and explicit recursion (which is good for learning but in the long run you should learn to use library functions). Also, since you are a new contributor, please remember to indicate useful answers.

Comment: I get `lisSum [('a',1), ('a',2)] [('a',3)] == [('a',4)]` but it should be `[('a',6)]` (see comments on the question).

Comment: I would in general expect that `lisEqual (lisSum l1 l2) (lisSum (permutation l1) (permutation l2) )` holds.

Comment: Also `lisEquals  [(0,0)] [] == True`.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x The comments are a bit contradictory since they also state that duplicates keys need not be considered. I think that in any sensible implementation of `lisSum` it must be true that `count a (lisSum xs ys) == count a xs + count a ys`. If you want the merging behavior for both equality and sums, all you need to do is change `count` to `sum [n|(x',n)<-xs, x' == x]`. If you want the contradictory behavior use either definition where it suits.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x The case of associations with 0 is already mentioned in the answer, the solution ignores it which is sensible with the counting semantics.

Comment: True, I overlooked the comment on the neutrality.

Answer (score 5):

Since `a` is only a member of `Eq`, sorting or grouping is not an option.

```
import Data.List(nub, (\\))
import Data.Monoid(getSum)

type Times = Int
type Lis a = [(a,Times)]

lisEqual :: Eq a => Lis a -> Lis a -> Bool
lisEqual xs xs' = length xs == length xs' && xs \\ xs' == []

lisSum :: Eq a => Lis a-> Lis a-> Lis a
lisSum xs xs' = fmap f $ getKeys l 
  where
    f x = (,) x (getSum . foldMap (pure . snd) . filter ((x ==) . fst) $ l)                         
    l = xs ++ xs'
    getKeys = nub . fst . unzip
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the version I proposed in the comments. First check the lists for duplicate keys and equal length to ensure that we only need to check if all keys of `l1` are keys of `l2`. Then do the lookup and check if the counts are equal:

```
lisEqual l1 l2 =
  (nodups $ map fst l1) &&
  (nodups $ map fst l2) &&
  length l1 == length l2 &&
  and (map (\ (x,k) -> case (occOfA x l2) of
                    Just n -> n == k
                    Nothing -> False
                  ) l1)
```

The lookup returns `Maybe b` to indicate a failed lookup with `Nothing`.

```
occOfA :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
occOfA a []   = Nothing
occOfA a ((x,n):xs) =
  if a == x then Just n
            else occOfA a xs
```

The duplicate checking is just a recursion

```
nodups :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
nodups [] = True
nodups (x:xs) = not (x `elem` xs) && (nodups xs)
```

Some test cases

```
t :: Int -> Bool
t 0 = lisEqual [(2,3), (1,2)] [(1,2), (2,3)] == True
t 1 = lisEqual [(2,3), (1,2)] [(1,3), (2,3)] == False
t 2 = lisEqual [(2,3), (1,2), (1,3)] [(1,3), (2,3)] == False
t 3 = lisEqual [(2,3)] [(1,3), (2,3)] == False
```

can be checked as

```
*Main> and $ map t [0..3]
True
```

I'm a bit lazy for computing the sums, I define a function `lisSum1` that collects all keys from list and sums up the values accordingly. For `lisSum` I just need to concatenate the two lists:

```
lisSum l1 l2 = lisSum1 $ l1 ++ l2

lisSum1 :: Eq a => [(a,Int)] -> [(a,Int)]
lisSum1 list =
   reverse $ foldl (\acc k ->  (k, sumList $ map snd (select k list) ) : acc ) -- create pairs (k, ksum) where ksum is the sum of all values with key k
   [] (rdups $ map fst list)
```

With some helper functions:

```
rdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rdups [] = []
rdups (x:xs) = x : rdups (filter (/= x) xs)

sum l = foldl (+) 0 l

select k list = filter (\ (x,_) -> k == x) list
```

Some tests again:

```
s :: Int -> Bool
s 0 = lisSum [('a',1), ('a',2)] [('a',3)] == [('a',6)]
s 1 = lisSum [(1,2), (2,3)] [(2,4),(3,1)] == [(1,2),(2,7),(3,1)]
s 2 = lisSum [(1,2), (2,3), (2,4), (3,1)] [] == [(1,2),(2,7),(3,1)]
s 3 = lisSum [(1,2), (2,3), (3,1)] [] == [(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)]


*Main> map s [0..3]
[True,True,True,True]
```

*Edit*: The function `lisEqual` is not reflexive because we originally defined a version that requires no duplicates in the input. The problem with this is that `lisEqual` is no equivalence relation:

```
*Main> lisEqual [(1,1),(1,2)] [(1,1),(1,2)]
False
```

If we fix the reflexivity, we can just remove the original restriction on duplicates and define:

```
lisEqualD [] []    = True
lisEqualD (_:_) [] = False
lisEqualD [] (_:_) = False
lisEqualD (x:xs) ys =
    case (remFirst x ys) of
        Nothing -> False
        Just zs -> lisEqualD xs zs

remFirst x [] = Nothing
remFirst x (y:ys) =
  if x == y then Just ys
            else case (remFirst x ys) of
                    Just zs -> Just (y:zs)
                    Nothing -> Nothing
```

Let's extend the test cases:

```
t :: Int -> Bool
t 0 = lisEqualD [(2,3), (1,2)] [(1,2), (2,3)] == True
t 1 = lisEqualD [(2,3), (1,2)] [(1,3), (2,3)] == False
t 2 = lisEqualD [(2,3), (1,2), (1,3)] [(1,3), (2,3)] == False
t 3 = lisEqualD [(2,3)] [(1,3), (2,3)] == False
t 4 = lisEqualD [(2,3), (1,2), (2,3)] [(1,2), (2,3),(2,3)] == True
t 5 = lisEqualD [(1,1),(1,2)] [(1,1),(1,2)] == True


*Main> map t [0..5]
[True,True,True,True,True,True]
```

Comment: Why should `lisEqual` return false for lists with duplicates? That means it's not reflexive since `lisEqual x x` would be false for some (invalid) lists. Perhaps it should yield an error instead (or ignore the duplicates since that is what the lookup function does).

Comment: The requirement was added in the comments. You are right about the reflexivity, this would be ugly - I'm thinking if i can salvage the property without errors, but if `lisEq [(1,2),(1,3)] [(1,3),(1,2)]` returns false but `lisEq [(1,2),(1,3)] [(1,2),(1,3)]` throws an error, this is also not a nice behaviour.

Comment: I added a better version that considers duplicates.

Comment: Also i would expect that `lisSum [] == id` (adding an empty map does nothing).

Comment: The property does not hold in general, take e.g. `lisSum [] [(1,2),(1,3)]`. I added a `reverse` to recover at least the cases where the keys in each list are all different.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is pretty straightforward. In order to compare such lists you need to order them first. Sum two list by key can be done recursively as long as the key is of type `Ord` and you order by key both lists. I am not using your aliases just to keep it primitive, but you can easily adapt it

```
eqList xs vs = xs' == vs' 
                 where xs' = sortOn fst xs
                       vs' = sortOn fst vs

sumKeyValue' :: [(Char, Integer)] -> [(Char, Integer)] -> [(Char, Integer)]
sumKeyValue' [] v  = v
sumKeyValue' x  [] = x
sumKeyValue' x@((a, c):xs) v@((b,d):vs) 
  | a == b = (a, c + d):sumKeyValue xs vs
  | a < b  = (a,c):sumKeyValue xs v
  | a > b  = (b,d):sumKeyValue x vs

sumKeyValue xs vs = sumKeyValue' xs' vs' 
  where xs' = sortOn fst xs
        vs' = sortOn fst vs
```

Comment: Your code has incompatible types with the functions requested in the question. And you can not easily adapt it, since you can not sort without an `Ord` constraint.

Comment: It's not that bad, you can remove duplicates from the list, zip it up with `[1.. length dups]` and use this mapping as an ordering, but it makes the solution less elegant.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x How would that ordering help with anything?

Comment: You can use an arbitrary ordering on the elements for sorting. Just assign numbers to elements at will and use them for sorting.

Comment: I don't think the `Ord` condition is such a problem as @lamda.x.y.x has pointed out. Moreover, up to the question (and editions) it seems that the actual type Is `[(Char, Int)]` rather than `[(a, Int)]` for any arbitrary `a` but maybe I am over asuming