# Converting a list to a data.map giving type error

Tags: list, haskell, hashmap

I am trying to convert a list to a data.map so that from a list like:

```
mylist = ["one","one","two","three","two","two","three","four","four","four","four","five","five","two"]
```

I get something like:

```
("one", 2)  ("two", 4) ...
```

I am trying following code:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.List 

list2dict [] mymap = print mymap
list2dict [y:ys] mymap = do
    if (Map.lookup y mymap) /= Nothing
    then list2dict [ys] $ Map.insert y ((Map.lookup y) + 1) mymap 
    else list2dict [ys] $ Map.insert y 1 mymap 

mylist = ["one","one","two","three","two","two","three","four","four","four","four","five","five","two"]
main = do
    list2dict (sort mylist) $ Map.empty
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
soq_list2dict.hs:5:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Show (Map.Map k a -> Maybe a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        list2dict :: forall a k.
                     (Show (Map.Map k a -> Maybe a), Show k, Ord k,
                      Num (Map.Map k a -> Maybe a), Eq (Map.Map k a -> Maybe a)) =>
                     [[k]] -> Map.Map k (Map.Map k a -> Maybe a) -> IO ()
```

How can this be solved?

Edit: using (y:ys) instead of [y:ys] gives following error:

```
soq_list2dict.hs:5:1: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: k ~ [k]
      Expected type: [[k]] -> Map.Map k (Map.Map k a -> Maybe a) -> IO ()
        Actual type: [k] -> Map.Map k (Map.Map k a -> Maybe a) -> IO ()
    • Relevant bindings include
        list2dict :: [[k]] -> Map.Map k (Map.Map k a -> Maybe a) -> IO ()
          (bound at soq_list2dict.hs:5:1)
```

Comment: A classic problem: it is `(x:ys)` with *round* brackets, not `[y:ys]`.

Comment: This does not work- gives some other error. I have added it to my question above.

Comment: You don't need to put brackets around `[ys]` when doing the recursive `list2dict` calls, since ys is already a list

Comment: I realized I do not need `(sort mylist)`- just `mylist` works.

Comment: See also my answer to [How to group similar items in a list using Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12398993/791604). tl;dr `list2dict xs = Map.fromListWith (+) [(x, 1) | x <- xs]`.

Comment: Very nice. Can such a function be used here to count occurrences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Willem Van Onsem already pointed out the first problem in a comment: you used `[y:ys]` instead of `(y:ys)`. The second problem is that you used `[ys]` instead of just `ys` in two places. The third problem is that you say `((Map.lookup y) + 1)`, which creates a nonsensical type. (Even if you had used `((Map.lookup y mymap) + 1)` instead, which is closer to correct, you still would have just gotten a different error.) This way will work instead:

```
list2dict (y:ys) mymap = case Map.lookup y mymap of
    Just x -> list2dict ys $ Map.insert y (x + 1) mymap
    Nothing -> list2dict ys $ Map.insert y 1 mymap
```

Note that I pattern-match on the `Maybe` rather than testing it with `if` and then trying to extract the value separately after that.

Comment: @rnso I don't know why and can't reproduce it. When I take your code and replace your second case of `list2dict`, it works perfectly with no other changes for me.

Comment: Yes, it works fine now. Probably some indentation problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You made a classic error: a non-empty list has as pattern `(x:xs)` (notice the empty brackets). But you make things too complicated here.

You can implement this with a `foldr` pattern, that can convert any `(Ord a, Foldable f) => f a` to a `(Ord a, Integral i) => Map a i`:

```
import Data.Map(Map, alter, empty)
import Data.Maybe(maybe)

toCounter :: (Ord a, Foldable f, Integral i) => f a -> Map a i
toCounter = foldr (alter (Just . maybe 1 (1+))) empty
```

We thus start with an `empty` map, and for each item in the `Foldable`, we perform an `alter` where, in case the item already exists (then it gives us a `Just n`, we return a `Just (n+1)`, and for a `Nothing` we fallback on `1`.

Since it works on `(Ord a, Foldable f) => f a`, you can make a "counter" for anything of a type that is an instance of the `Ord` typeclass, and is stored in a object of a type that is an instance of a `Foldable`. So it can count items in a list, `Maybe` (well this has exactly one or no item), a `Tree`, etc.

For example:

```
*Main> toCounter ["one","one","two","three","two","two","three","four","four","four","four","five","five","two"]
fromList [("five",2),("four",4),("one",2),("three",2),("two",4)]
```

A shorter version, that works on lists is one written by [@DavidFletcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960636/converting-a-list-to-a-data-map-giving-type-error/57960752?noredirect=1#comment102333381_57960752):

```
import Data.Map(Map, fromListWith)

toCounter :: (Ord a, Integral i) => [a] -> Map a i
toCounter = fromListWith (+) . map (flip (,) 1)
```

we can however use `toList` to let it work with `Foldable`s as well:

```
import Data.Foldable(toList)
import Data.Map(Map, fromListWith)

toCounter :: (Ord a, Foldable f, Integral i) => f a -> Map a i
toCounter = fromListWith (+) . map (flip (,) 1) . toList
```

Comment: Feels like you are almost reinventing `fromListWith` with the fold and alter.  I'd do something like (untested): `fromListWith (+) . map (flip (,) 1)`

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. But other one is simpler for me to understand.