# Filter a list of tuples and return the first item based on a condition that applies to the second item

Tags: list, haskell, filter, tuples

The task is as follows: I have a list of tuples containing country names, and the official language. I have another list with "3 item tuples" of translators in *(first name, last name, language)* format. I need to get a list of the countries, which official language is NOT spoken by any of the translators.

It has to be one call to a function of such form:

```
foo :: [(String, String)] -> [(String, String, String)] -> [String]
```

I have tried all sorts of `map` and `filter` combinations to no avail. The closest I came was using sets.

```
third :: (a, b, c) -> c  
third (_, _, z) = z  

translators x = Set.fromList (map third x)
languages x = Set.fromList (map snd x)

diff x y = Set.toList (Set.difference (languages x) (translators y))
```

This gives me all the languages that are in the first list but not spoken by the translators. However of course, the task is to give a list of the country names, not the languages. So I tried this as well, but it does not work:

```
foo x y = filter ((Set.notMember (translators y)).snd) x
```

I'm a beginner and I would much appreciate some help.

Comment: To nudge you in the right direction rather than spitting out an answer, can you solve a simpler problem?  Given a country and an interpreter, can you write a function that will tell you whether or not that interpreter can translate that country's language?  I'd start there, then figure out how to use that predicate function as a filter.

Comment: can there only be one country associated with each language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first function gives you the correct answer - except it gives you the list of languages. How about an assoc list so you can lookup country associated with the language?

To do that, you just have to [`swap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html#v%3aswap) the country and language in the `(Country, Language)` tuple

```hs
import Data.Tuple ( swap )

langMap :: [(String, String)] -> [(String, String)]
langMap = map swap
```

Now once you have the result of your own `diff` function, you just have to map a [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup) function over the resulting list

```hs
diff :: [(String, String)] -> [(String, String, String)] -> [String]
diff x y = map (fromJust . (`lookup` langMap')) diffList
    where
        diffList = Set.toList $ Set.difference (languages x) (translators y)
        langMap' = langMap x
```

If you are concerned about performance, you can replace the assoc list by a [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.9.1/docs/Data-Map.html)

```hs
import qualified Data.Map as Map

langMap :: [(String, String)] -> Map.Map String String
langMap = Map.fromList . map swap
```

And also change the `lookup` in `diff` to `Map.lookup`.

```hs
diff :: [(String, String)] -> [(String, String, String)] -> [String]
diff x y = map (fromJust . (`Map.lookup` langMap')) diffList
    where
        diffList = Set.toList $ Set.difference (languages x) (translators y)
        langMap' = langMap x
```

However, there's one caveat here - the `lookup` method will only work if you have only one country associated with each language.

If you want to support the situation when there are multiple countries associated with the same language. You need some extra batteries on the `langMap`-

```hs
langMap :: [(String, String)] -> Map.Map String [String]
langMap x = Map.fromListWith (++) [(v, [k]) | (k, v) <- x]
```

This is a slight modification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12398993/10305477). It creates a map of `String` and `[String]`. The key string is the language, and the value is a list of countries

Now, since the value of the map is a list of strings instead of just a string - we also need to change the `diff` a bit

```hs
diff :: [(String, String)] -> [(String, String)] -> [String]
diff x y = concatMap (fromJust . (`Map.lookup` langMap')) diffList
    where
        diffList = Set.toList $ Set.difference (languages x) (translators y)
        langMap' = langMap x
```

Huh, that was simple. Just changing `map` to `concatMap` is enough - it'll flatten the list of list of strings, into just a list of strings.

Let's see it in action-

```hs
λ> xs = [("US", "English"), ("Mexico", "Spanish"), ("France", "French"), ("Spain", "Spanish"), ("UK", "English"), ("Italy", "Italian")]
λ> ys = [("Foo", "Spanish"), ("Bar", "French")]
λ> diff xs ys
["UK","US","Italy"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This is a synthax question but how does lookup in "map (fromJust . (`lookup` langMap')) diffList" know what to look up? I understand fromJust recieves the output of lookup on langMap, and that we map the whole thing to every element of the difflist.

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on correctness, on solving the problem, not on the solution being an efficient one. That we can take care of later. Correctness first, efficiency later!

Simplest and most visual way to code this is using List Comprehensions.

```
foo :: [(String, String)] -> [(String, String, String)] -> [String]
--       Country Language      FirstN  LastN   Language

-- return: list of Contries with no translator
foo cls nnls = [ c | (c, ___) <- cls,  -- for each country/language pair,
                     -- test the {list of ()s for each translator that ...}
                     ___ [ () | (_, _, ___) <- nnls, ___ == ___] ]
```

Fill in the `___` blanks (you don't have to fill the `_` blanks, those are Haskell's anonymous, throwaway variables).

Now you can make it efficient, treating the above as executable specification.