# Reverse list of tuples of nodes and edges (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a list of nodes and edges, represented as tuples where the first element is a node, and the second element is a list of all nodes it has an edge to. I am trying to reverse the list like so:

```
ghci> snuN [("a",["b"]),("b",["c"]),("c",["a","d"]),("e",["d"])]
ghci> [("a",["c"]),("b",["a"]),("c",["b"]),("d",["c","e"]),("e",[])]
```

So far, I've written this code:

```
snuH :: Eq t => [(t,[t])] -> [(t,[t])]
snuH [] = []
snuH ps@((x, xs):rest) =
    if (length xs <= 1) && not (x `isInSublist` ps)
        then [(y,[x])| y <- xs] ++ snuH rest ++ [(x, [])]
    else [(y,[x])| y <- xs] ++ snuH rest

isInSublist :: Eq t => t -> [(t,[t])] -> Bool
isInSublist _ [] = False
isInSublist x ((y, ys):rest) = (x `elem` ys) || isInSublist x rest

combine :: Eq t => [(t,[t])] -> [(t,[t])]
combine ps@((x, xs):(y, ys):rest) = if x == y then (x, xs++ys):rest else (x, xs):combine((y, ys):rest)

snuN :: Eq t => [(t, [t])] -> [(t, [t])]
snuN ls = combine $ snuH ls
```

The first function gives me this output:

```
ghci> snuH [("a",["b"]),("b",["c"]),("c",["a","d"]),("e",["d"])]
ghci> [("b",["a"]),("c",["b"]),("a",["c"]),("d",["c"]),("d",["e"]),("e",[]),("b",[])]
```

Which is not quite the result I wanted, because it creates two tuples with the same first element (`("d",["c"]),("d",["e"])`), and it has the extra `("b",[])` as an element when it shouldn't. I wrote the `combine` helper-function to fix the problem, which gives me this output:

```
ghci> snuN [("a",["b"]),("b",["c"]),("c",["a","d"]),("e",["d"])]
ghci> [("b",["a"]),("c",["b"]),("a",["c"]),("d",["c","e"]),("e",[]),("b",[])]
```

Which fixes the problem with the two tuples with the same first element, but I still have the extra `("b",[])` which I can't figure out how to fix, I assume there's something wrong with my `snuH` but I can't see where the problem is.

Can you tell me what im doing wrong here? I don't understan why I get the extra `("b",[])`. All help is appreciated!

Comment: You are only combining adjacent elements, but elements may have the same `fst` part without being adjacent. See [How to group similar items in a list using Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12398458/791604) for a long compendium of alternative solutions.

Comment: I did see that question before I asked a question here myself, but I didn't understand their use of `fromListWith` and I didn't want to include somethind I didn't know about. If I use their solution I get `fromList` in the output, and I didn't know how to remove it from the output, so I tried an alternative approach.

Comment: you remove `fromList` from that output by calling `toList` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd argue that the following list comprehension gives you what you need:

```
type Graph node = [(node, [node])]

converse :: Eq node => Graph node -> Graph node
converse g = [(v, [e | (e, es) <- g, v `elem` es]) | (v, _) <- g]
```

However, if you try it out, you'll get:

```
> converse [("a",["b"]),("b",["c"]),("c",["a","d"]),("e",["d"])]
[("a",["c"]),("b",["a"]),("c",["b"]),("e",[])]
```

Compared to the example you gave, the entry for `"d"` is missing from the output. That's because the input did not mention an explicit entry `("d", [])`.

---

To compensate for this, we could put a bit more logic in retrieving the complete list of nodes from the graph, also accounting for the "implied" ones:

```
nodes :: Eq node => Graph node -> [node]
nodes g = nub $ concat [v : es | (v, es) <- g]
```

Note: this requires importing `nub` from `Data.List`.

Then, we can write:

```
converse' :: Eq node => Graph node -> Graph node
converse' g = [(v, [e | (e, es) <- g, v `elem` es]) | v <- nodes g]
```

And, indeed, we yield:

```
> converse' [("a",["b"]),("b",["c"]),("c",["a","d"]),("e",["d"])]
[("a",["c"]),("b",["a"]),("c",["b"]),("d",["c","e"]),("e",[])]
```

Comment: Which nodes should be considered "explicit" and which "implied" would seem to depend on the implementation technique.

Answer (score 1):

You have `[(a, [a])]`, which maps nodes to the nodes they have an edge to. One approach to "reversing" this is to first convert it to a list of all the edges. We can actually generalize the type a bit here, to distinguish from and to nodes.

```hs
allEdges :: [(a, [b])] -> [(a, b)]
allEdges g = [(a, b) | (a, bs) <- g, b <- bs]
```

Now it's just a matter of gathering up the nodes with an edge *to* each particular node:

```
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

gather :: Ord b => [(a,b)] -> Map b [a]
gather edges = M.fromListWith (++) [(b, [a]) | (a, b) <- edges]
```

Now we can just use `M.assocs` to convert that map to a list!

The above code will leave out nodes that have no edges going *to* them. We can patch that up with a bit of extra work.

```
reverseGraph :: Ord a => [(a, [a])] -> [(a, [a])]
reverseGraph = M.assocs . M.fromListWith (++) . gunk
  where
    gunk g = [q  | (a, bs) <- g, q <- (a, []) : [(b, [a]) | b <- bs]]
```

The idea here is that when we see `(a, bs)`, we insert the empty edge set `(a, [])` along with the nonempty ones `(b, [a]` for each `b` in `bs`.